# Primefaces datePicker format date

Tags: java, date, jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces and I have a datePicker `<p:datePicker id="birthDate" value="#{accountBean.accountModel.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>` and I have an model like this :

```
public class AccountModel implements Serializable{

    public String accountId;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public Date birthDate;
    public boolean allowNegativeBalance;
    public BigDecimal balance;
    
    // Getter Setter
}
```

The problem is when I try to `System.out.println(accountModel.getBirthDate());` the result is `Tue Feb 23 00:00:00 ICT 1997` (Date) . How to make the `Tue Feb 23 00:00:00 ICT 1997` (Date) to `1997-02-23` (Date) when I access the getter of my model? Thank you.

Comment: Use `LocalDate` whose `toString` returns the value in the form `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead as @ArvindKumarAvinash said use `LocalDate` [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If i use java.time.LocalDate, i got other error : javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void com.daksa.mockvaJsf.bean.AccountBean.init() on com.daksa.mockvaJsf.bean.AccountBean@df6d586 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory :) Thanks.

Comment: Ah, for use with Jackson you also need [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). Go ahead.

Comment: @OleV.V. Perfect! Thank you!